# Minimum Spanning Tree given that a specific vertex v should have a degree(v)=k

Tags: algorithm, graph, kruskals-algorithm

Let's say we have an undirected graph G(E,V) and a given vertex v . I want to find a Minimum Spanning Tree T  , so that degree(v)=k in T.

- I have considered finding all the adjacent vertices of v in G.
- find q (q=degree(v))  Minimum Spanning Trees  (1 starting from every vertex adjacent to v) using a modified Kruskal .
- Convert those MSTs into supervertices ,and now I have v and degree(v) MSTs
- Now connect all the above ,using a modified kruskal in order to make sure that degree(v)=k

Can someone confirm that my algorithm is going to find the right result? maybe suggest a different approach ?

Comment: This is a [matroid intersection problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid_intersection) so you can use the matroid intersection algorithm. There might be a more elementary approach though.

Comment: Does anything cross your mind as far as the more elementary approach is concerned? I would be grateful if you threw some hints or a simple idea to have something to start from.

Comment: This problem is slightly simpler than the matrix intersection problem in full generality, and you can use techniques such as those described in [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1109/SFCS.1979.14), which includes the precise problem you are asking about. Unfortunately, I do not have a link to the full text of this paper.

Comment: Good news! I have found a full text for a [similar paper](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a461278.pdf). You will find Section 4.2 useful, though the rest of the paper is useful preliminaries if you are not yet comfortable with the vocabulary around matroid intersection.